# Sort data on ListView using time from database as a String variable in ascending order?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView, cursor adapter and a sqlite database. I receive data from the database and it displays on the ListView. I would like to sort the data from the value 'beginTime' in my code in ascending order. 'beginTime' is retrieved as a String from the database.How can I go about it?

**Monday Class**

```
public class Monday extends Fragment {
FloatingActionButton fab;
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Database db;
String timeEnd;
String timeBegin;
String lEnd;
String lBegin;
EditText lName;
String day;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_monday, container, false);
   db = new Database(getActivity());
    String DAY = "Monday";
     Cursor cursor= db.getDayLessons(DAY);


    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),cursor);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.attachToListView(listView);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

                                     }

                                     @Override
                                     public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                     }
                                 }

    );

   /* listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });*/
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent x = new Intent(getActivity(), LessonDetails.class);
            x.putExtra("day","Monday");
            x.putExtra("Tab","0");
            x.putExtra("weekDay","2");
            startActivity(x);
            getActivity();
        }
    });

    return v;

      }
   }
```

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);

}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lesson_list, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    final TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    TextView tvVenue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvVenue);

    ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    ImageButton edit = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonEdit);
    final String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.DAY_COLUMN));

    final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.ID_COLUMN));
    final String id = String.valueOf(_id);
    final int intent = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.INTENT_COLUMN));
    final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.NAME_COLUMN));
    String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.BEGIN_TIME_COLUMN)) + "-" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.END_TIME_COLUMN)) + "h";
    String venue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.VENUE_COLUMN));


    tvName.setText(name);
    tvTime.setText(time);
    tvVenue.setText(venue);


    delete.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Database db = new Database(context);
            db.deleteLesson(_id);
            cancelPre(context, intent);
            cancelActual(context, intent);
            cursor.requery();
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
    edit.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent p = new Intent(context, EditLessons.class);
            p.putExtra("Row_selected", id);
            context.startActivity(p);


        }
    });
}

public static Comparator<Integer> ascending = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer integer, Integer t1) {
        return t1.compareTo(integer);
    }


};

public void cancelActual(Context context, int rq) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Lessons.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rq, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


}

public void cancelPre(Context context, int rq) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Lessons.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rq, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
  }
}
```

**Sqlite Database Class**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public static final String LESSON_TABLE = "LESSONS";
public static final String DAY_COLUMN= "Day";
public static final String ID_COLUMN= "_id";
public static final String VENUE_COLUMN = "Venue";
public static final String INTENT_COLUMN = "INTENT";
public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "Name";

public static final String BEGIN_TIME_COLUMN = "BeginTime";
public static final String END_TIME_COLUMN = "EndTime";
public static final int VERSION = 1;


public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String query = "create table " + LESSON_TABLE + "(" + ID_COLUMN + " integer primary key autoincrement," + DAY_COLUMN + " varchar," + NAME_COLUMN + " varchar," + BEGIN_TIME_COLUMN + " varchar," + END_TIME_COLUMN + " varchar," + VENUE_COLUMN + " varchar," + INTENT_COLUMN + " integer" + ")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    String drop = "drop table if exists " + LESSON_TABLE;
    db.execSQL(drop);
   onCreate(db);

}

public void addLesson(Lesson lesson)throws SQLiteException
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME_COLUMN,lesson.getName());
    values.put(DAY_COLUMN,lesson.getDay());
    values.put(BEGIN_TIME_COLUMN,lesson.getBeginTime());
    values.put(END_TIME_COLUMN,lesson.getEndTime());
    values.put(VENUE_COLUMN, lesson.getVenue());
    values.put(INTENT_COLUMN, lesson.getIntent());
    db.insert(LESSON_TABLE, null, values);
    //db.close();

}
 public Cursor getDayLessons(String day) throws SQLiteException {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + LESSON_TABLE + " where " + DAY_COLUMN + "='" + day + "'",);
     if (mcursor != null) {
         mcursor.moveToFirst();

     }

         return mcursor;
     }


public void updateLesson(String name, String bTime, String eTime, String venue, int _id)
{
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME_COLUMN,name);
    values.put(BEGIN_TIME_COLUMN,bTime);
    values.put(END_TIME_COLUMN,eTime);
    values.put(VENUE_COLUMN,venue);

    db.update(LESSON_TABLE, values, ID_COLUMN + "='" + _id + "'", null);
   // db.close();

}
public void deleteLesson(int id)
{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(LESSON_TABLE,ID_COLUMN + "='" + id + "'",null);
   // db.close();


}
public Cursor getLesson(int _id)
{
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + LESSON_TABLE + " where " + ID_COLUMN + "='" + _id + "'", null);
    if (mcursor!=null)
    {
        mcursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mcursor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use db query to retrieve your data in desired order.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY begintime ASC;
```

begintime should be in milliseconds or [iso format](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm).